# Upper/lower AM/PM in Menubar clock -- different between Macs

Tags: macos, internationalization, time

My Mac is configured for the **Australia** region.

I have one Mac running Sonoma 14.4 that displays my time in the menubar as:

```
Mon 25 Mar 4:30 PM
```

I have another Mac running Sonoma 14.3.1 that shows it as:

```
Mon 25 Mar 4:30 pm
```

Note the difference between `PM` and `pm`.

Are there setting anywhere that I can use to standardise this display?

I doubt that it's due to the different OS version, but I'd be interested to see whether other users have this discrepancy.

Here's the settings screen for 14.4, which is identical to 14.3.1 except for the upper/lower PM:

[image: Mac Regional settings]

Comment: Did you notice this discrepancy when the 14.4 Mac was running 14.3.1?

Comment: No, I didn't notice it before. Right now, it "hits me in the face" because I notice the difference. I guess I'll update the 14.3.1 (work machine) to 14.4 when permitted and see if it makes a similar change.